# How to use Google Analytics on my embeddable widget?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm providing a simple embeddable js widget that people can put on their site.

I'd like to track impressions and behavior.

What's the right way to integrate Google Analytics on this widget?
Most likely the host page will already have Google Analytics so I shouldn't interfere with it, and the events should be sent to my own GA account.

Comment: I really hope  that this is not possible (and where I live it would be quite possibly be illegal) since this would return a lot of data about the host site that's none of your business (plus you'd probably mess up the host sites utm cookies). Much better to get the impressions from your own server logs (if the widget code is pulled from your own server) and implement some limited form of tracking for widget actions (maybe a call to a pixel on your own server for each action - even then you should inform the wigdet users  that data is sent to some unknown (to them) destination on the internet)

Comment: Why would it be illegal? I don't want/need any data of the host site, just the widget. And I'd even be satisfied with only measuring impressions for the sake of measuring virality, I don't really care who's viewing it. Of course I can implement it on my own but who wants to create analytics infrastructure  when Google Analytics exists?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar needs to elado, thanks for your post.

This was my recent post https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/analytics/-/HuMDDvKupLQJ

Hope that its possible to simply track interactions on my widget, not concerned about the host site or blog statistics.